# Page Preview redirects to Login Page even tho the user is logged in

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

If I click on the preview button in the presentation or publish tabs, the user is redirected to the login page.

The web.config has site the site definition:

```xml
<name="website" loginPage="/login.aspx" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Home" database="web" domain="extranet" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" />
```

The user has access to preview. I am using Sitecore 8.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: instead of preview of page, it asks for login credintials

Comment: Is there any custom processor at your solution code? If yes try to stop them to see if one of them is the problem? also do you have this problem in all items or specific items? do you have any specific security permissions on that item? Is your site upgraded or a new instance?

Comment: What security setting do you have on the page you are trying to preview?

Comment: Which login page? The sitecore login page or a custom one for your site?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `loginPage="/login.aspx"` from your `<site ... />` and see if that helps. Also, note that clicking the preview button from the Publish ribbon will open the site in preview mode in a new tab but clicking preview from the Presentation ribbon will open an editor frame preview of the site but it may resolve the context site as *shell*.